# angular 2 unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

so I updated nodejs and before that happened. The angular 2 didn't get the error and it was working fine but now updating the node_modules it stopped working and I have no clue where the error would be or how to fix it.

```
(index):29 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js:15:22)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js:70:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js:71:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/profile/profile.component.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js:15:22)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js:70:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js:71:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/profile/profile.component.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
        'angular2-jwt': 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vietnam Films</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ecommerce.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>



    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);  });
    </script>
    <script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-9.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>



    <div class="loading">
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is a good chance you are actually getting a 404 not found error on some file. Of course with Angular we're supposed to redirect 404s to the index.html page, which you are probably doing correctly. To see if this is the case, configure your webserver to actually return the 404 to see which file is missing. OR look at the network traffic in the browser dev tools to see if any requests are returning the index.html page instead of the correct file.

Comment: I finally found the error, the chrome browser console was too vague and i looked at the firefox console and it said that I was missing a node module.

Answer (score 0):

Dev tools are your friend.  Open up Chrome dev tools while you access the page and check the network tab.  Look at the individual requests.  I am guessing that the `http://localhost:3000/app/services/authentication.service.js` request isn't returning the javascript you're hoping for, and is instead returning a HTML error page.  Check out what that error is, and you will find the culprit.  Most likely it is just not finding the file at all (HTTP 404), but best to check the error.

If it is 404, then make sure that authentication.service.js is properly located in the app/services directory you're serving from.